# How to display and show special characters like "ü" ,"ö" "ä" etc. in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-browser

In my Neo4j graph-database, I have some data with special characters like "ä", "ö" etc. 
If I start a query, e.g

```
MATCH (v:Verein)-[:plays_against]->(V:Verein) WHERE v.name = "1.FC Köln" RETURN v
```

The query returns no data.
How can I fix this problem

The data was before imported from a MySQL-database. the database had already utf-8 encoding.

```
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `bundesliga` /*!40100 DEFAULT 
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci */;
```

Comment: If the data is loaded successfully then there should not be any issues. I added node and then searched it works. ```MATCH (v:Verein) WHERE v.name = "1.FC Köln" RETURN v.```

Comment: Check if your database is loaded successfully.

Comment: After I executed this query: `CREATE (v:Verein {name: "1.FC Köln"})-[:plays_against]->(V:Verein {name: "Mainz"})`, your query returns the `v` node for me. Are you sure your data import actually generated an **outgoing** `:plays_against` relationship for the "1.FC Köln" node? Does changing `->` to `-` work?